# All to make a conditional type with all possible generics?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have this types:

```
type IInputType = "text" | "checkbox" | "number";

type IField<T extends IInputType> = {
  name: string;
  value: 
   T extends "checkbox" ? boolean : 
   T extends "number" ? number : 
   string;
  type: T;
};

type IPossibleFieldTypes = IField<IInputType>;
```

That way the conditional is not working because field.value is typed as string, number or boolean, and not only boolean as should:

```
 // field type is IPossibleFieldTypes 
 if (field.type === "checkbox") {
  // Here field.value should only be boolean
  // but TS are allowing string or number too
 }
```

But if I specify the possible IFields manually:

```
type IPossibleFieldTypes =
  | IField<"text">
  | IField<"checkbox">
  | IField<"number">;
```

Now the types are being displayed correctly:

```
 if (field.type === "checkbox") {
  // Here field.value can only be boolean
 }
```

The question is:

There is a way to make this type work (IPossibleFieldTypes) without have to manually set the possible generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `IField` a distributive conditional type, so that you make a discriminated union:

```
type IInputType = keyof ValueMap;

type ValueMap = {
    text: string;
    checkbox: boolean;
    number: number;
};

type IField<T extends IInputType> = T extends T ? {
    name: string;
    value: ValueMap[T];
    type: T;
} : never;
```

Also, we take advantage of the fact that `T` is a string, which means instead of a long chain of conditional types, we can use another type that maps `T` to the right type. Then narrowing will work correctly:

```
if (field.type === "checkbox") {
    field.value;
    //    ^? boolean
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKOnKW)

Comment: @DaniloCunha Oh of course... `type IInputType = keyof ValueMap;` - I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong logic in `value`, where `T extends IInputType` which is with every type is true. Just do this way:

```
type IField<T extends IInputType> = {
  name: string;
  value: 
   "checkbox" extends T ? boolean : 
   "number" extends T ? number : 
   string;
  type: T;
};
```

And this fix your code.